# The getter 'postersImageUrl' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: postersImageUrl

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have successfully stored my firebase info into PostData however, when I try to get it, it gives me the error:

> The getter 'postersImageUrl' was called on null.
>
> Receiver: null
>
> Tried calling: postersImageUrl

I don't know why I am getting this since I have stored the data. There isn't anything wrong with storing the data, just displaying it.
Please message underneath if more info is needed and I can provide.

```
  Visibility(
    visible: !hideHeader,
    child: ListTile(
      leading:
          profileImageWidget(profileImageUrl: postData.postersImageUrl),
      title: Text(
        postData.postersName,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          color: Color(0xFF356B8F),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ProfileScreen(
              userToken: postData.postersId,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

**Here is how my PostData class looks.**

```
class PostData with ChangeNotifier{
  int likesCount;
  List likes;
  int timestamp;
  String postersName;
  String postersId;
  String postersImageUrl;
  List postSavedByUsers;
  String title;
  String id;
  String description;
  double price;
  String imageUrl;
  String productCategoryName;
  String brand;
  bool isPopular;
  PostData({
    this.likesCount,
    this.likes,
    this.timestamp,
    this.postersName,
    this.postersId,
    this.postersImageUrl,
    this.postSavedByUsers,
    this.title,
    this.id,
    this.description,
    this.price,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.productCategoryName,
    this.brand,
    this.isPopular,
  });

  PostDatas(

      int likesCount,
      List likes,
      int timestamp,

      String postersName,
      String postersId,
      String postersImageUrl,
      List postSavedByUsers,
        title,
      String id,
      String description,
      double price,
      String imageUrl,
      String productCategoryName,
      String brand,
      bool isPopular,
      )
  {

    this.likesCount = likesCount;
    this.likes = likes;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;

    this.postersName = postersName;
    this.postersId = postersId;
    this.postersImageUrl = postersImageUrl;
    this.postSavedByUsers = postSavedByUsers;
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.productCategoryName = productCategoryName;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.isPopular = isPopular;
  }

  PostData.zero();

  PostData mapToObject(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return PostDatas(

        map["likes_count"],

        map["likes"],
        map["timestamp"],

        map["posters_name"],
        map["posters_id"],
        map["posters_image_url"],
        map["post_saved"],
        map["title"],
        map["id"],
        map["description"],
        map["price"],
        map["imageUrl"],
        map["productCategoryName"],
        map["brand"],
        map["isPopular"],
    );
  }

  List<PostData> forArrayToObject(
      List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> data) {
    List<PostData> postListData = [];
    for (var object in data) {
      postListData.add(mapToObject(object.data()));
    }
    return postListData;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {

      "likes_count": this.likesCount,
      "likes": this.likes,
      "posters_name": this.postersName,
      "posters_id": this.postersId,
      "posters_image_url": this.postersImageUrl,
      "post_saved": this.postSavedByUsers,
      "title": this.title,
      "id": this.id,
      "timestamp": this.timestamp,


      "description": this.description,
      "price": this.price,
      "imageUrl": this.imageUrl,
      "productCategoryName": this.productCategoryName,
      "brand": this.brand,
      "isPopular": this.isPopular,

    };
    return map;
  }

}
```

Comment: It seems like `postData` in the call `postData.postersImageUrl` is `null`. It's impossible to say why that is though without seeing how you initialize `postData`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hello, thank you, I have just included my postdata object. If there is anything else that is needed to solve the problem, I can provide it as well.

Comment: It's not so much about that class, but about where you initialize the `postData` variable.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, I don't think I initialized my postData variable in the main since its a class I made up, do I need to also initialize it in main?

Comment: If you never initialize `postData`, then accessing `postData.postersImageUrl` will always give the error you get. It's good that you have a `PostData`, but your widget doesn't have any way to know what `postData` is until you initialize it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, would I initialize postData in the postData class? Sort of like declaring a Map using a Map Constructor?